# How to untar specific files from a number of tar files and zip them?

Tags: bash, zip, tar

The requirement is to extract all the *.properties files from multiple tars and put them into a zip.

I tried this:

```
 find . -iwholename "*/ext*/*.tar.gz"|xargs -n 1 tar --wildcards '*.properties'  -xvzf | zip -@ tar-properties.zip
```

This is creating a zip with the .properties files in all the tars.

But the issue is the tars are structured as in each tar contains a properties folder which contains the files. The above command is creating a zip with a single properties folder which contains all the files .

Is there a way to put these in the zip with a folder structure like {name of the tar}/properties/*.properties ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this script. My solution uses `--transform` as well. Please check first if your `tar` command supports it with `tar --help 2>&1 | grep -Fe --transform`.

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ] || {
    echo "You need bash to run this script." >&2
    exit 1
}

TEMPDIR=/tmp/properties-files
OUTPUTFILE=$PWD/tar-properties.zip  ## Must be an absolute path.

IFS=

if [[ ! -d $TEMPDIR ]]; then
    mkdir -p "$TEMPDIR" || {
        echo "Unable to create temporary directory $TEMPDIR." >&2
        exit 1
    }
fi

NAMES=()

while read -r FILE; do
    NAMEOFTAR=${FILE##*/}  ## Remove dir part.
    NAMEOFTAR=${NAMEOFTAR%.tar.gz} to remove extension  ## Remove .tar.gz.

    echo "Extracting $FILE."

    tar --wildcards '*.properties' -xvzf "$FILE" -C "$TEMPDIR" --transform "s@.*/@${NAMEOFTAR//@/\\@}/properties/@" || {
        echo "An error occurred extracting to $TEMPDIR." >&2
        exit 1
    }

    NAMES+=("$NAMEOFTAR")
done < <(exec find . -type f -iwholename '*/ext*/*.tar.gz')

(
    cd "$TEMPDIR" >/dev/null || {
        echo "Unable to change directory to $TEMPDIR."
        exit 1
    }

    zip -a "$OUTPUTFILE" "${NAMES[@]}"
)
```

Save it to a script then run it on the directory where those files are to be searched with

```
bash /path/to/script.sh`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do the trick with `tar` option `--transform, --xform`. This option permits to manipulate path thanks to a `sed` expression.

```
find . -iwholename "*/ext*/*.tar.gz"|xargs -n 1 tar --wildcards '*.properties'  -xvzf --xform 's#.*/#name_of_the_tar/properties/#' | zip -@ tar-properties.zip
```